# Tkinter: saving image results in quality lost

Tags: python, image, canvas, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I read a picture and display it in a Canvas:

```
 im=the_canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor="nw",image=img)
```

After that, I save it:

```
 returned_value=the_canvas.postscript(file="saved.ps", height=image_h, width=image_w, colormode="color")
 r=Image.open("saved.ps")
 r.save("saved.png")
```

How can I save the image in png or jpg formats without loosing its quality ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sadly, there is no format that the Tkinter canvas can natively save to other than postscript.  Are you trying to save modifications made to the image via drawing functions on the canvas?  My recommendation is to use the Python Imaging Library functions.  Whatever you're doing on the canvas, do the same thing behind the scenes on a copy of the image using PIL's functions.

Comment: @Brionius ok, thank you for the information. I will have to learn about PIL then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
        from PIL import Image,ImageTK

        save_name=filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
        canvas.postscript(file=save_name+".eps") # save canvas as encapsulated postscript
        img = Image.open(save_name+".eps")
        img.save(save_name+".png", "png",quality=99)
```

This will save the image as a png.